# Image containers initially appear collapsed, than images appear one by one

Tags: html, css

It's an know issue that "with fluidly sized images, before the images load, the image containers initially appear collapsed."

I've fixed the issue for banner image and product images adding div and using this css hack:

```
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding-bottom: 66.6%;
position: relative;
```

But can't understand how to fix it for awards icons block.

Firstly image containers initially appear collapsed, than it's loading one big icon, than 2nd, than resize them - would like it to know correct sizes before hand so it will look smooth to the eye.

Here is the [screen recording](https://puu.sh/xLjc1/4091fe5481.mp4) of the issue

Here is pen for award icons block > https://codepen.io/anon/pen/borJXK

**HTML**

```
<div class="awards-memberships-container" data-modal="#awards-memberships-modal">
    <div class="awards-memberships">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/188x132"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/146x146"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/204x133"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img{vertical-align:bottom;}
body section img{max-width:100%;height:auto;}
.awards-memberships-container{background:#FFF;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;cursor:pointer;}
.awards-memberships{display:flex;padding:5px 15px;}
.awards-memberships .item{padding:0px 10px;}
```

Comment: Would setting a height to your `.items` work ?

Comment: Consider adding this snippet of CSS: `.awards-memberships .item { min-height: 132px; }`. The `.item`s will be 132px high during page load, and then as the images load in will grow as much as they need.

Comment: @ProEvilz, thanks for your suggestion. It's responsive design, so what looks good one screen width, may look not so nice on smaller/bigger screen width. I though there might be some other solution.

Comment: @get9 Well from what I can see here... your images are **not** responsive?

Comment: @ProEvilz, maybe responsive is not the right term. To make it look properly on high resolution screens we make image source 2 times larger than they actually displayed. What I've meant by responsive is that if screen width is higher image will display at higher width (for example on iPhone 6 plus images will be displayed a little bigger than on iPhone 6)

Comment: @get9 So that means you're programmatically changing the image... in that same part of the code that handles that, simply change the height depending on the image aswell...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and tell me how it goes.

```css
body section img {max-width:100%;height:auto;}
.awards-memberships-container {background:#FFF;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;cursor:pointer;}
.awards-memberships {display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;padding:5px 15px;}
.awards-memberships .item {padding:0px 10px;}
.awards-memberships .item img {display:block;width:auto;height:auto;max-width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="awards-memberships-container" data-modal="#awards-memberships-modal">
  <div class="awards-memberships">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/188x132" alt="img1">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/146x146" alt="img2">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/204x133" alt="img3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```